# How to add text to an xml structure using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to add a text field to a xml structure using xmlstarlet, but can't get it to work. This is the closest I got.

```
xmlstarlet edit --append "//foo/bar[@baz='qux']" -t text -n grault -v "garply" <<EOF
<foo>
   <bar baz="qux">
     <quux quuz="corge"/>
   </bar>
</foo>
EOF
```

This results in :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar baz="qux">
    <quux quuz="corge"/>
  </bar>garply
</foo>
```

While I expected this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar baz="qux">
    <quux quuz="corge"/>
    <grault>garply</grault>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Can someone enlighten me about the errors of my ways?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need a subnode:

```
xmlstarlet edit --subnode "//foo/bar" -t elem -n "grault" -v "garply" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar baz="qux">
    <quux quuz="corge"/>
    <grault>garply</grault>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

See: `xmlstarlet edit`